# How to view adobeconnect video offline?

Tags: video, vlc, adobe-flash, media

I want to watch some lectures created with adobeconnect. I have the lectures downloaded to my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Each one consists of a stream that includes a video window of the professor lecturing (with audio) and another video window of his shared desktop. There is also some text/chat conversation from the students.

Each lecture consists of these files:

```
cameraVoip_1_4.flv
cameraVoip_1_4.xml
ftchat0.flv
ftchat0.xml
ftcontent1.flv
ftcontent1.xml
ftstage3.flv
ftstage3.xml
indexstream.flv
indexstream.xml
mainstream.flv
mainstream.xml
screenshare_0_2.flv
screenshare_0_2.xml
telephony-files.xml
transcriptstream.flv
transcriptstream.xml
```

I can watch just the professor (audio and video) in this file:
**cameraVoip_1_4.flv**

The professor's share desktop is in this file:
**screenshare_0_2.flv**

(I haven't found the file with the student chat stream yet & I don't know what content is in the other files or if they are needed at all.)

I can currently open each of the two flv files above in two different players (such as VLC & SM Player) and manually synchronize them, but that's a pain.

**Is there a better way I view this content on Linux?**

The main problem with the two-different-players approach is keeping the two streams synchronized. For example, I cannot easily back up and I cannot easily skip over the class break period. It is almost never the case that I just start the two players, synchronize them once and then listen to an entire 2 hour lecture. It always turns into a giant hassle that makes me not want to watch the lectures. I need a better way.

Answer (score -1):

According to Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Connect

it should be possible to run Adobe Connect on the following systems:

- Microsoft Windows
- Mac OS X
- Solaris
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux
- Novell SUSE Linux

The question is, whether or not you have access to either iso image files or CDs/DVDs of the following systems: Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X and Solaris. If you do then maybe you could try to install a Windows Version on a virtual machine inside Oracle's Virtualbox and use this virtual machine exclusively for your lectures.

But even if you don't have access to the iso image files, mentioned above, you could still download an iso image from the Fedora Project:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29

Because it says in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux :

> Fedora serves as upstream for future versions of RHEL

Or you could download an iso image file for SuSE Linux and install that in a Virtualbox VM on your Ubuntu host system.

In both cases you could then install Adobe Connect inside the SuSE VM or the Fedora VM.

Comment: This doesn't really answer his Q. I think the OP is asking more how to do this, not what you've described.

Comment: According to the links, the Wikipedia article is referring to the Adobe Connect **server**. I am looking for a client application for viewing.

Comment: @mountainx Am I correct in my assumption that you already looked at the following viewer for Adobe Connect sessions? http://www.adobe.com/support/connect/downloads-updates.html There is even a player for Ubuntu there.

Comment: @ChristopherSchmidt - I don't see anything at that link that is relevant. Those are viewers for viewing online content being streamed from an Adobe Connect server. My question is how do I view that OFFLINE (i.e., not connecting to an Adobe Connect server). I already have the files downloaded.

Comment: @mountainx Two more questions: Do you have access (- perhaps through a student account -) to an iso image file of windows and what kind of Adobe Connect version does your professor use? Maybe there's a clue to the Adobe Connect version in the xml-files. The reason for this is the following information for Adobe Connect 9 on the website, you can access through the last link, I have given you: "Please note that although there is currently no Add-in for Linux, users on Linux (Ubuntu, Red Hat and OpenSUSE) can still attend, host, or present in meetings in the browser."

Comment: @mountainx I just wonder, whether it is possible to load an offline lecture into an Adobe Connect server and then access that lecture throught localhost from a client. This is, why I'm asking these questions.